PyMuPDF page.search_for(text) splits a line break into two completely different objects
I use PyMuPDF for document redaction. Sometimes I want to redact only one instance of a certain text on a page, so I use an index:
areas = page.search_for(text)
area = areas[index]

The problem is that if there is a line break in the middle of the phrase I was looking for, or certain designs that split the text, it turns it into two different instances and confuses my index
Is there no way to detect whether multiple objects belong to the same single expression?

This is an inevitable thing! Even more: if your text contains hyphenated words like "meth-" and "od" on a new line, you will get 2 hit rectangles. This is as it must be! However, you can be sure that all returned hit rectangles belong to the same search response. Your code redacting the text must be smart enough to cope with situations like these. There is no problem adding as many redaction annotations as you have hit rectangles and remove old text in all of them in one single apply_redactions(). Filling new text in the resulting gaps again requires smart programming!

The one potential problem might be that the same search finds multiple occurrences of the needle. This can only be checked by extracting the text in the hit rectangles, split it into words and compare that word list with that of the needle.

@JorjMcKie thank you for your answer, it helped me a lot.
you can see in the answer below the code I created to combine the parts of the results. kind of messy but works.
i really like your project, such a good work.

here's what worked for me:
I created a list of lists, and each instance was inserted into the list at the required index by character count
def merge_results(page, text):
    text_len = len(text)
    rl = page.search_for(text)
    text_search = []
    sum_len = 0
    index = 0
    for rectangle in rl:
        if len(text_search) <= index:
            text_search.append([])
        text_part = len(page.get_textbox(rectangle))
        if text_part < text_len:
            sum_len += text_part
            text_search[index].append(rectangle)
            if sum_len >= text_len:
                sum_len = 0
                index += 1
        else:
            text_search[index].append(rectangle)
            index += 1
    return text_search

